# Prove that if $n$ is odd, then $-n$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here is my work so far, I am missing something quite obvious but I can't seem to link it together:

Proof.
Let $n$ be an integer.
Suppose $n$ is odd.
This means that there is an integer $k$ such that $n = 2k + 1$.
So $-n = -2k-1$ ...
Thus, there is an integer $m$ such that $-n = 2m + 1$; namely, $m = ?$
Therefore, $-n$ is odd.

I'm stuck after I wrote $-2k-1$.

Comment: Note that $-2k-1=-2k-2+1=-2(k+1)+1=2(-k-1)+1.$

Comment: All replies were very helpful. This one fits the style I needed the best. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 5):

You got off to a great start!

All that's left (to figure out what $m$ should be) is to set $$2m+1=-2k-1,$$ and solve for $m.$

Answer (score 3):

The sum of an odd and an even number is odd.  If $-n$ were even, then $0 = n + (-n)$ would be odd, absurd.

Comment: +1, this was my immediate thought. In fact, it is not even necessary to go about it by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even then $-n$ is even, suppose $n=2k$, then $-n=2(-k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is odd. Then for some integer $k$, $n = 2k+1$.

This implies that $$-n = -(2k+1) = -2k-1 = -2k-1+(2-2)=-2k-2-1+2 = -2k-2+1$$
which is $2(-k-1)+1$. Indeed, $-k - 1$ is an integer, so the proof is done.

The main trick here was to add and subtract $2$ to turn the $-1$ into a $+1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will keep my eye out for the tricks next time, I haven't completed many proofs yet. Thanks!